# Resizeable widget in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've got a `ListView` item with three components aligned horizontally:

1. an `ImageView` containing an icon
2. a `TextView` with a headline
3. another `ImageView` wit a status icon

Currently, I have them arranged via a `RelativeLayout` and my `TextView` is 'elastic'.

Is it possible to create the same layout in `ConstraintLayout`? Basically, what I'm asking is if I can create 2 fixed-length constraints instead of percentages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, do the following, with the elements contains in a ConstraintLayout such as:

```
ImageView1 TextView ImageView2
```

- ImageView1 : constraint left to ConstraintLayout left side
- ImageView2 : constraint right to ConstraintLayout right side
- TextView

  - constraint left to ImageView1 right side
  - constraint right to ImageView2 left side
  - layout_width="0dp"

"0dp" tells CL to stretch the widget up to meet the constraints set. You can add margins on the constraints as well.

Comment: Works even with included layouts. Thank you

Comment: That `0dp` does it for me! For others who're interested in reading documentation, check the **Widgets dimension constraints** heading in [ConstraintLayout reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).